# AlertDialog.Builder show(), crash in click handler

Tags: java, android

My app opens a new view from the main view with:

```
Intent ElementsIntent = new Intent(this, ElementList.class);
startActivityForResult(ElementsIntent, 0);
```

which shows a list of elements and when pushing 1 of these elements a view opens up the same way as before with a new Activity. Inside this view I would like to show a  AlertDialog in a button click handler, but when I call show() the app crashes.

I am pretty sure it has got somthing to do with the Context not being correct according to where I try and open the dialog, but I have tried making a static context from the main view, I have tried with element.this, which is the class connected to the activity, and I have tried getApplicationContext, and all of these result in an app crash.

I hope someone can explain what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Here is the AlertDialog code which crashes:

```
public void GoBackClickHandler(View v)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ElementItem.this);
    builder.setMessage("Skal ændringer i besvarelse gemmes?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Ja", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   dialog.cancel();
                if(inputIsValue())
                {
                    UpdateELement task = new UpdateELement();
                    task.applicationContext = ElementItem.this;
                    task.execute(1);
                }
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("Nej", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    finish();
               }
           });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();       
}
```

If I move this code to the OnCreate, then the alert shows just fine and no app crash. It is only if I place it in a ClickHandler it crashes.

Comment: We will need the code that launches the AlertDialog to help you out.

Comment: If your in an anonymous class, Activity.this is usually an easy way to get the context

Comment: Hi, I also went through the same kind of situation, I created AlertDialog inside handler. It crashes at the point where click event is added, however it works properly when even is removed. For this you need to implement the OnClickListener in some other class and create object of that, and add that object as listener for this AlertDialog...! Handler heap segment gets removed once it is completely executed, so it is not able to find the event instance, and thus giver error: NoClassDefError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a soloution to this issue.

I had to save the context of the Activity in a variable in the onCreate method and then use this in the ClickHandler AlertDialog call, then everything works.

Hope this will be of help to someone else with this annoying problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

    //Object to hold the listener instance
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Assign this to listener.
        listener = this;

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Alert");
                builder.setMessage("Alert Message...!");

                //Here pass the listener object.
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", SplashActivity.this.listener);
                builder.show();

            }

        });

    }

    @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            SplashActivity.this.finish();
        }

}
```